# MVC DataAnnotation MaxLength fails when input is all strings

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a data annotation for an MVCV5 project which validates correctly in most instances. However if the user enters only spaces (e.g 4 spaces) the validation doesn't catch it on the client side (although the validation catches it on posting). Is there a way to get these to validate correctly on the client side?

```cs
[StringLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 3 characters")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{0,3}$", ErrorMessage = "Area code should be 3 digits only")]
public string AreaCode { get; set; }
```

I'm using the following libraries:

```
jQuery.Validation: version 1.13.1
Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation: version 3.2.3
```

Comment: As far as the jQuery Validate plugin is concerned, a field containing only four spaces is still considered empty.  However, when validating `minlength` the leading spaces are only counted if there is also non-empty character.  There are no other tricks or workaround.   If you think this is a bug or that it should work differently, you'll have to contact the developer on his GitHub page.    http://jsfiddle.net/Lst6puxc/

Comment: Sparky, I think you're right. There are a couple of places the jquery.validate.js file looks for: "this.optional( element )" but should probably look for "(this.optional( element )==true)". I put it in two places and then the validation worked. When the field has only spaces the "this.optional( element )" call is returning "dependency-mismatch".

Comment: Looks like they fixed the issue. https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/1498

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Model level validation using IValidateObject and then use IsNullOrWhiteSpace property to validate empty string/null/white spaces.

```
public class Model : IValidatableObject 
{ 
   public string FirstName { get; set; } 
} 

public IEnumerable<ValidationResult>Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) 
{ 
   if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName)) 
   { 
      yield return new ValidationResult("First Name Required", new string[] { "FirstName" }); 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're limiting the input to 3 characters, the quick way is to be explicit about it with `maxlength`:

```
<input type='text' maxlength="3"...
```

As for spaces (only), jquery validate should catch that with `required`. Hth

Comment: Yeah, it has the attribute data-val-length-max="3" on it, but still doesn't seem to catch spaces. I didn't put in required because it's an optional field.

Comment: @GnomeCubed Not `data` attribute, [standard HTML `input` field `maxlength` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). If it's not "required" then it can have spaces, and you'll have to create a custom jquery validation rule for it.

Comment: I was hoping to do this using the built-in annotations in my project so I don't have to manually edit a bunch of html attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue pretty simply by looking at the "optional" function.

The optional function (according to this blog post):
http://lagod.id.au/blog/?p=514&cpage=1#comment-213145 Is NOT telling you whether the field is optional. It is just telling you whether the field is empty.

The optional function returns:

```
!$.validator.methods.required.call( this, val, element ) && "dependency-mismatch";
```

So I looked at the required method and noticed it's trimming the field value before checking its length.

It's a simple fix, so instead of returning:

```
$.trim( value ).length > 0;
```

I had it set it to return:

```
value.length > 0;
```

That causes it to validate fields even if you enter just one space. So now my zipcode validates if you enter even one space in it because it's supposed to only allow numbers.